# javascript listen during 10 minutes for a http post request, if not cancel it

Tags: javascript, http-post, httprequest, listen

I am developing a little bitcoin payment platform. I am using nodejs as backend and html5 and javascript as frontend. Ok i coded the part where i receive the callback of the payment being done notification in nodejs and post a 'paid' string to the client. In the client side i need write a code to be waiting during 10 minutes for that POST request. If the request does not arrive in that 10 minutes the payment is cancelled.

I just have no clue on how to make the frontend listen to a http POST request during 10 minutes and cancel it if it does not arrive in that period..

Regards,
Aitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "POST" TO the client.
Also 10 minutes would be too long to set for a request timeout ( as browser would timeout before then - about 2 mins max depending on browser)

You can do polling after the request has been POSTed (from the client to the nodejs backend) - you'd use AJAX for that

Or you could set up a WebSockets socket.io connection and "push" a result from the nodejs backend to the client - see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Comment: seems like using node.js socket.io module will help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
$.ajax({url:"your url", timeout: 1000*60*10, success:function(result){
    //handle response here...
}});
```

Change "your url" to your url. This code will make an ajax call to your server and when it responds, it will enter the success: function with the result. The timeout of 1000*60*10 is in milliseconds and evaluates to 10 minutes.

Comment: Please provide some explanation for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the timer for do this.
set a timer width the java script,check the POST parameter that if received or no. and when the time finished you can redirect the user to an other page.